# Stop outgoing mail being picked up as SPAM

Tags: email, cpanel, spam, mail-server

I've setup a testing platform for a client to test a login system on subdirectory of one of my domains. The Client keeps complaining the emails sent by the server arent getting to them and the users. My immediate thought is that their servers are filtering them as most of the addresses are public sector domains and they have very strict filters.

What i would like to know is there anything else I can do make sure my emails arent being picked up as spam. Ive checked the Cpanel and the Track Delivery page shows the mail as being recieved but the spam score is 2, i cant find any documentation on what this 2 means and all other sources tell me about balcklists etc and how not to get on them. Can anyone shed any light on this or help?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question, there is so many things involved in getting emails delivered, often people think it's something that happens magically.

First Things first, most ESP "Email Service Providers" (Your Gmail, hotmail, aols') have different [Postmaster Guideline](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/postmasterguidelines/) that should be followed. But fortunately there is a lot of overlap.

Make sure you have all your basic email authentication set up

- SPF (I think is one of the most important)
- DKIM (Second Most Important)
- DMARC (Protects your brand, spoofed emails from you)

Make sure you have abuse@ and postmaster@ accounts set up from your sending domain.

You can test all the basic authentication for free with [Mail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/emailauthentication/)

Once you move past the configuration and authentication aspects of email, you need to focus on your "Reputation". In order to do that you should sign up for [Email Feedback Loops](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/resources/feedbackloops/). Feedback loops are a way to let you know what people are marking your emails as spam and you need to remove those people from your mailing lists, since they are hurting you "Reputation"

When you have a low sender reputation - That's when you run into deliver-ability problems. You can monitor your reputation at [Sender Score](https://www.senderscore.org/)

Blacklists - Their are public and their are private blacklists, the private ones you are on are hard to identify. You'll have to review bounce backs to see if the mail server is letting you know. The public ones, their are hundreds, you can scan them [here](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/blacklist/bl/) for free.

Usually, having the right authentication and configuration in place, coupled with feedback loops. Will keep your Sender Reputation high and off the blacklists. Most companies will frequently monitor all aspects of email deliver-ability to ensure email flow for their customers. So you'll need to set up a process to process the email feedback loops, monitor blacklists, evaluate DMARC reports, etc.

Comment: But how can i apply any of this to my situation? I am only looking to use my subdirectory of the domain to send emails for testing purposes with my clients, long term solution wont really apply

Comment: You should apply this to any situation when you are sending email. When you say "Sub directory" do you mean sub-domain?  Like subdomain.domain.com?

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important things is making sure the IP address is not marked as spam and that the you have a reverse proxy setup by your ISP. Many of the highlevel spam filters look for reverse proxy.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You will have to do the following things if your emails are moving to the SPAM instead of INBOX,

> (1) Set SPF Record
>
> (2) Set DKIM Record.
>
> (3) Set DMARC and rDNS (PTR) Record.
>
> (4) You will need to check if your ip address is blacklisted at RBLs.
>   https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx/. You can submit delist request
>   at RBLs if it is listed.

If the issue persists you can check the email log or header to confirm the possible cause.